# Developing firewall rules for an application

Tags: web-services, firewall, sandbox

As part of my work experience (I am 17 and at sixth form) the IT technicians have asked me to prepare for a deployment of autocad Fusion 360, and the application needs to talk to the autocad servers in order to run and start. However the current proxy and firewall configuration are preventing it from running. So I figure I need to know the ports and destination for where and how the application is trying to communicate to.

So far I have installed Wireshark and started up the application and collected the packets the computer has sent out in the time frame the application was running which I feel is a step in the right direction. So I now have an idea of the ports and destination.

I would be grateful if someone would suggest a program I could run the application in (I am thinking of a sandbox type of application) which will allow me to simulate a firewall so I can add my own rule to fine tune the ports, etc. needed to run the application.

Comment: Why not reading the documentation of the software? It should indicate at some point which ports and hosts it wants to connect to. Failing that, looking at your firewall logs for blocked connections should highlight the failed connection attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Oracle VirtualBox or VMware Workstation or VMware ESXi —

You can install the whole OS, and do whatever inside of them. Then monitor what comes out.

Comment: Yes, VirtualBox is simpler I think. He needs a Windows image (iso) https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-10-in-VirtualBox